# Can I use a US PSN account with Reg ALL physical copies?

Tags: psn, region-lock

When I visit the store to buy Freedom Wars PS Vita, there are only Reg ALL/Asia for physical copies.  As far I know the downloadable content in region 3 (Asia) copies only works with a Play Station Network region 3 account.  But how about Reg ALL/Asia?

If I had region 1 (US) account Play Station Network, can I download downloadable content in store and install it, when my physical copies are Reg ALL/Asia?

Comment: Probably not. If you only have access to the US PSN store on your Vita, then the DLC you download there will only work on US/Canadian copies.

Comment: Asking here will not get you "official clarification".

Comment: Some user experience are welcome. I just want the example 'REG ALL' can or can't download the DLC if available in store.